# Как объединить несколько моделей в одном реквесте?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть класс OrderRequest, с помощью него нужно получить информацию из разных моделей. Сейчас мой код выглядит так:

```
class OrderRequest extends FormRequest
{
    
    public function getOrder(): Order
    {
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = Order::withTrashed()->findOrFail($this->route('order_id'));
        return $order;
    }
}
```

Потом в OrderController вызываю эти методы:

```
public function show(OrderRequest $request): View
{
    return view($this->viewsPath . self::SHOW_ACTION, [
        'model' => $request->getOrder(),
    ]);
}
```

И в show.blade.php вывожу результат.

Можно ли как-то переписать функции в OrderRequest?

Comment: Обычно `FormRequest` используется для валидации входящих данных, у Вас там явно не валидация происходит.

Comment: Кажется, понял свою ошибку. Как я понял, весь код выше должен содержать только функцию ```getOrder()``` (добавил изменения). А в миграциях надо уже настраивать отношения (relations) к таблицам ```OrderDish```, ```OrderPlace```, ```Dishes```. Но проблема-то в том, что основной таблицей в базе идет ```Order```, а уже от него берется поле ```id``` и вставляется в  ```OrderDish```, ```OrderPlace```. И в миграциях эти файлы идут в таком порядке.

Comment: Нет, этот код вообще не должен быть внутри `OrderRequest` и я не понимаю почему Вы решили что ему там место. `FormRequest` используется для валидации входящих данных, обычно там присутствует метод `rules()` с правилами описывающими валидацию. Ознакомьтесь с [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation). Так же почитайте про [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships), то что Вы описали как проблему -- довольно тривиальная вещь, если читать документацию.